# Place label at center of doughnut chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, charts, mschart

I've developed a web page with MS Chart (.net framework 2.0, visual studio 2010).
Like this picture, I have to put the percentage label inside the doughnut.

[image]

What can I do? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi,Please post the code that you have tried..

Comment: Add a `TextAnnotation` to your chart.

Comment: I just used built in properties... there are only 3 attributes, "inside", "outside", "disabled"..
>> Chart.Series["Series"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Inside";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `PrePaint` event to add a `TextAnnotation` to your chart:

[image]

```
protected void Chart1_PrePaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChartElement is ChartArea)
    {
        var ta = new TextAnnotation();
        ta.Text = "81%";
        ta.Width = e.Position.Width;
        ta.Height = e.Position.Height;
        ta.X = e.Position.X;
        ta.Y = e.Position.Y;
        ta.Font = new Font("Ms Sans Serif", 16, FontStyle.Bold);

        Chart1.Annotations.Add(ta);
    }
}
```

Comment: @jsanalytics  How to draw a circle inside the chart instead of text?

Comment: @abhishek use `e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawEllipse()`.

Comment: @jsanalytics what cordinates to pass?

Comment: @abhishek , any coordinates that suit you. As a suggestion you probably want to calculate it from `Width` and `Height` as shown in my answer above.